# Why gurobi outputs a wrong final solution while the right solution is already found in earlier iteration?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I'm new to Gurobipy. When I use Gurobipy to solve a task-scheduling problem, I designed a very simple case and I already know the optimal value is 33.7(s). It seems Gurobi actually found the optimal solution, just in the first few iterations, the output is as follows:

```
Explored 1 nodes (124 simplex iterations) in 0.01 seconds (0.01 work units)
Thread count was 8 (of 8 available processors)

Solution count 1: 33.7 

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 3.370000000000e+01, best bound 3.370000000000e+01, gap 0.0000%
```

After this, it outputs a wrong final solution as follows:

```
Explored 1 nodes (100 simplex iterations) in 0.01 seconds (0.01 work units)
Thread count was 8 (of 8 available processors)

Solution count 1: 0 

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 0.000000000000e+00, best bound 0.000000000000e+00, gap 0.0000%
IIS runtime: 0.01 seconds (0.01 work units)
```

0 is obviously not the right value. Why is that happening? Why Gurobi turns to a wrong solution even after it finds a optimal in the fisrt place?

Gurobipy should stop solving the model when it finds the optimal problem, but it outputs a wrong solution.

Comment: Is "wrong" suboptimal or constraint breaking? Show your code.

Comment: More log details would be helpful as well.